# Repeat VBA Find across subsequent columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

As you'll probably be able to tell from the code, I'm pretty new to VBA, so apologies if this turns out to be a stupid question.

I need a block of code that looks at one worksheet (RawData) for a text string specified in the Global variable Verb1, and pastes it into the first empty column of a different worksheet (Verbatim).

My difficulty is that the string stored in Verb1 could appear 1, 2, or 3 times in RawData, so I need the Find function to check multiple columns, even after it's found the first occurrence of the string.

What my code is actually doing, however, is copying the column that holds the first occurrence of the string, and pasting it a number of times equal to the number of columns in my search range... in this case, 688 times.

I've checked that the code works without the For... Next statement (i.e. it finds the first occurrence of the string, and pastes it into the first blank column of the Verbatim worksheet), but I can't see what the error is in this statement.

```
Public Verb1 As String

Sub Paste2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim NextCol As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Verbatim")
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A1:ZZ1")
NextCol = 0

Worksheets("RawData").Activate
With ws1
'Copy and Paste Verbatim
For Each Cell in Rng
    NextCol = NextCol + 1
    Set aCell = Worksheets("RawData").Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=Verb1, 
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    aCell.EntireColumn.Copy ws2.Cells(1, NextCol)
Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way using `.FindNext`, and cleaning up some of your code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Verb1 As String

Sub Paste2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim NextCol As Long
Dim sFirstAddress As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Verbatim")
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A1:ZZ1")
NextCol = 0

'No need to "Activate"
'Worksheets("RawData").Activate

With Rng
'Copy and Paste Verbatim
    Set aCell = .Find(what:=Verb1, after:=Rng.End(xlToRight), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAddress = aCell.Address
        NextCol = NextCol + 1
        aCell.EntireColumn.Copy ws2.Cells(1, NextCol)

        Do
            Set aCell = .FindNext(aCell)
            If Not aCell.Address = sFirstAddress Then
                NextCol = NextCol + 1
                aCell.EntireColumn.Copy ws2.Cells(1, NextCol)
            End If
        Loop Until sFirstAddress = aCell.Address
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked beautifully, and the cleaning up of my code is much appreciated too.

Comment: @mantika I would be appreciative if you could mark my response as the answer, by clicking on the checkmark below the ratings indicator

Answer (score 1):

You should add the option for `After` to `Set aCell`:

First, right before the `With` statement, add `Set aCell = rng.Cells(1, 1)`. Then switch the `Set aCell` to:

```
Set aCell = Worksheets("RawData").Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=Verb1, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, after:=aCell)
```

Also, there may be a more elegant way, but since you're looping through the cells in the range *regardless* if you've found all instances of the string, you could add a quick `COUNTIF()` to see how many times you should be copying the info:

```
Sub Paste2()

Dim ws1     As Worksheet, ws2     As Worksheet
Dim aCell   As Range, rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim NextCol As Long, numOccur As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Verbatim")
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A1:ZZ1")
NextCol = 0

numOccur = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Verb1)

Set aCell = rng.Cells(1, 1)
With ws1
    'Copy and Paste Verbatim
    For Each cel In rng
        NextCol = NextCol + 1
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=Verb1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=aCell)
        Debug.Print Verb1 & " found in cell " & aCell.Address
        aCell.EntireColumn.Copy ws2.Cells(1, NextCol)
        If NextCol = numOccur Then Exit For
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With `SearchDirection:=xlNext` I think it would be better to start off with `Set aCell = rng.Cells(1, rng.columns.count)`.

Comment: @Jeeped - Ahh, good point. That would have the cell start at the *end* of the range, and then go forward, right? Would you therefore no longer need the `COUNTIF()` part?

Comment: Actually, I'm unclear on the exit point for that For .. Next loop. The OP's narrative doesn't make sense to me without a [mcve].